# Duda básica sobre "Property" en Python

Tags: python, poo

Estoy aprendiendo python 3 en mis ratos libres, en concreto estoy viendo la parte de OOP (clases/objetos etc), como "emular" una clase privada en python y vi el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
# using property class
class Celsius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature * 1.8) + 32

    # getter
    def get_temperature(self):
        print("Getting value...")
        return self._temperature

    # setter
    def set_temperature(self, value):
        print(value)
        print("Setting value...")
        if value < -273.15:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273.15 is not possible")
        self._temperature = value

    # creating a property object
    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)


human = Celsius(37)

print(human.temperature)

print(human.to_fahrenheit())

human.temperature = -300
```

Y da la siguiente salida:

```
Setting value...
Getting value...
37
Getting value...
98.60000000000001
Setting value...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 31, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 18, in set_temperature
ValueError: Temperature below -273.15 is not possible
```

Obviad las últimas 5 líneas de la salida, ya que se corresponden al intento "fallido" de intentar introducir una temperatura no apta, fuera del intervalo marcado por el "if".

Lo que me llamó la atención, tras trastear con el cachito de código, es justo la salida que tiene antes, cuando convierte la temperatura a farenheit, es decir, la parte del:

> ```
> print(human.to_fahrenheit())
> ```

Según yo, esa parte debería dar como salida directamente el valor de la temperatura en farenheit, es decir, debería dar "98.60000000000001". ¿Por qué también imprime el "Getting value..." en pantalla?

Eliminando la línea:

> ```
> temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)
> ```

salen directamente los valores, a si que imagino que los tiros irán en cómo funciona exactamente ese "property". ¿Por qué me está interpretando un trozo de código, el `#getter`, si al poner `print(human.to_fahrenheit())` estoy referenciando a otro trozo de código distinto?

Igual suena como una duda muy tonta, pero llevo todo el día (y parte de mis horas de sueño) buscando al respecto y no conseguí encontrar ninguna explicación sobre esto. Tampoco es que sea algo trascendental, podría aprenderlo tal cual y olvidarme, pero me gusta entender estos detalles.

Comment: Bienvenido Lumme a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Revisa la identación de tu código, particularmente los dos primeros métodos pareciera estar mal.

Comment: Me parece que tu problema es casi un error tipografico, estas usando internamente la propiedad `self.temperature` y `self._temperature`  en distintos métodos. Creo que tu intención o en todo caso lo que deberías hacer, es manejar internamente el valor de temperatura como `self._temperature` por que en definitiva lo que terminas haciendo cuando invocas `property()`  es sobrescribir esta variable.